# MySQL Query Slowing Down on introduction of Where Clause

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, where-clause, query-optimization

I am writing a MySQL procedure that calculates proxy costs for inventory items added in physical inventory audits. I have created a cost map that contains date and product wise proxy costs and another 'inventory_assisted_cost' map that contains inventory id and proxy costs (based on inventory audit date and product).

To iterate this process in the procedure, I first calculate the minimum inventory id which meets the condition of being an audit item, having 0 cost, is present in the cost map and is not present in the 'inventory_assisted_cost'. If I run this query fragment without the where null clauses, I get the result in 0.5 sec. As soon as I add the where null / where not null clauses execution times goes above 10 minutes.

Here is the version of the query without the where clauses:

```
select fi.id
from flat_inventories fi 
left join fi_cogs_map fcm on fcm.product_id = fi.product_id and fi.id between fcm.min_fi and fcm.max_fi
left join fi_assisted_costs fac on fac.flat_inventory_id = fi.id
where fi.source_type = 'audit' and fi.unit_cost = 0
and fi.status not in ('lost','damaged','expired','invalid')
and fi.storage_id not in (select s.id from niyoweb.storages s where s.zone = 'virtual' or s.category = 'virtual')
and fi.warehouse_id > 1
and fcm.product_id is not null
limit 1
```

Here is the output of the explain query for the above:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | fi | ref | flat_inventories_warehouse_id_foreign,flat_inventories_source_type_source_id_index,flat_inventories_status_index | flat_inventories_source_type_source_id_index | 767 | const | 6405844 | 3.1 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | fcm | ref | fi_cogs_map_product_id_index,fi_cogs_map_min_fi_index,fi_cogs_map_max_fi_index | fi_cogs_map_product_id_index | 4 | fi.product_id | 3 | 100 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | fac | ref | fi_assisted_costs_flat_inventory_id,fi_assisted_costs_assisted_cost_basis,fi_assisted_costs_flat_inventory_id_unique | fi_assisted_costs_assisted_cost_basis | 8 | fi.id | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 2 | SUBQUERY | s | ALL | PRIMARY |  |  |  | 23669 | 19 | Using where |

Here is the version of the query with the where clauses:

```
select fi.id
from flat_inventories fi 
left join fi_cogs_map fcm on fcm.product_id = fi.product_id and fi.id between fcm.min_fi and fcm.max_fi
left join fi_assisted_costs fac on fac.flat_inventory_id = fi.id
where fi.source_type = 'audit' and fi.unit_cost = 0
and fi.status not in ('lost','damaged','expired','invalid')
and fi.storage_id not in (select s.id from niyoweb.storages s where s.zone = 'virtual' or s.category = 'virtual')
and fi.warehouse_id > 1
and fcm.product_id is not null 
and fac.flat_inventory_id is null
limit 1
```

Here is the output of the explain query for the above:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | fi | ref | PRIMARY,flat_inventories_warehouse_id_foreign,flat_inventories_source_type_source_id_index,flat_inventories_index_composite,flat_inventories_status_index | flat_inventories_source_type_source_id_index | 767 | const | 6405844 | 3.1 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | fcm | ref | fi_cogs_map_product_id_index,fi_cogs_map_min_fi_index,fi_cogs_map_max_fi_index | fi_cogs_map_product_id_index | 4 | fi.product_id | 3 | 11.11 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | fac | ref | fi_assisted_costs_flat_inventory_id,fi_assisted_costs_assisted_cost_basis,fi_assisted_costs_flat_inventory_id_unique | fi_assisted_costs_assisted_cost_basis | 8 | fi.id | 1 | 100 | Using where; Not exists; Using index |
| 2 | SUBQUERY | s | ALL | PRIMARY |  |  |  | 23669 | 19 | Using where |

I am at a loss as to how to get this to work with the additional where clause.

Edit:

Here are the DDL for the four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `flat_inventories` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `storage_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturing_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_cost` decimal(11,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`warehouse_id`),
  KEY `flat_inventories_storage_id_foreign` (`storage_id`),
  KEY `flat_inventories_warehouse_id_foreign` (`warehouse_id`),
  KEY `flat_inventories_source_type_source_id_index` (`source_type`,`source_id`),
  KEY `flat_inventories_index_composite` (`product_id`,`warehouse_id`,`status` DESC),
  KEY `flat_inventories_status_index` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=140432680 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `fi_cogs_map` (
  `fi_grp_by` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_fi` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_fi` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_fi_crt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_fi_crt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `fi_ids` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `src_ids` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pids` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_mrp` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketer_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `level_id` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cl4_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cl3_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cl2_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cl1_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_basis` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fi_crt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `prd_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grp_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brd_cl4_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brd_cl3_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brd_cl2_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brd_cl1_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mkt_cl4_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mkt_cl3_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mkt_cl2_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mkt_cl1_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cl4_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cl3_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cl2_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cl1_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `fi_cogs_map_min_date_index` (`min_date` DESC),
  KEY `fi_cogs_map_max_date_index` (`max_date` DESC),
  KEY `fi_cogs_map_product_id_index` (`product_id`),
  KEY `fi_cogs_map_min_fi_index` (`min_fi`),
  KEY `fi_cogs_map_max_fi_index` (`max_fi`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `fi_assisted_costs` (
  `flat_inventory_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `assisted_cost` decimal(15,6) DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `assisted_cost_basis` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`flat_inventory_id`),
  KEY `fi_assisted_costs_assisted_cost_basis` (`assisted_cost_basis`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `storages` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `warehouse_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sequence_id` double(13,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `length` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `width` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight_capacity` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `storages_warehouse_id_zone_index` (`warehouse_id`,`zone`),
  KEY `storages_warehouse_id_label_index` (`warehouse_id`,`label`),
  CONSTRAINT `storages_warehouse_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`warehouse_id`) REFERENCES `warehouses` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27614 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Indexes in Flat Inventories

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| flat_inventories | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 134134576 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| flat_inventories | 0 | PRIMARY | 2 | warehouse_id | A | 134128376 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| flat_inventories | 1 | flat_inventories_storage_id_foreign | 1 | storage_id | A | 199163 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| flat_inventories | 1 | flat_inventories_warehouse_id_foreign | 1 | warehouse_id | A | 4415 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| flat_inventories | 1 | flat_inventories_source_type_source_id_index | 1 | source_type | A | 1305 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| flat_inventories | 1 | flat_inventories_source_type_source_id_index | 2 | source_id | A | 5931168 |  |  | YES | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| flat_inventories | 1 | flat_inventories_index_composite | 1 | product_id | A | 316274 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| flat_inventories | 1 | flat_inventories_index_composite | 2 | warehouse_id | A | 498305 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| flat_inventories | 1 | flat_inventories_index_composite | 3 | status | D | 513456 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| flat_inventories | 1 | flat_inventories_status_index | 1 | status | A | 3631 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |

Count in Flat Inventories by Status

| status | count(fi.id) |
| --- | --- |
| audit_bad | 109760 |
| audit_blocked | 21828 |
| audit_hold | 133631 |
| audit_loss | 1683656 |
| billed | 38480 |
| bundled | 22920 |
| cancelled | 23 |
| damaged | 128977 |
| deleted | 421074 |
| delivered | 123509123 |
| dispatched | 173295 |
| disputed | 248171 |
| expired | 188399 |
| hold | 19849 |
| invalid | 55531 |
| liquidated | 4462382 |
| liquidated_manual | 85049 |
| lost | 882495 |
| manifested | 130 |
| picked | 117430 |
| putaway | 85473 |
| putaway_cancelled_shipment | 283 |
| putaway_return | 27221 |
| putaway_rto | 10444 |
| putaway_sto | 4693 |
| putway_return | 7 |
| ready_for_sale | 1750057 |
| rto | 276656 |
| sold | 3355983 |
| unbundled | 612 |

Count in Flat Inventories by Source Type

| source_type | count(fi.id) |
| --- | --- |
| audit | 2796338 |
| bundle_recipe | 9873 |
| bundled | 2423 |
| grn | 131064751 |
| order | 2619 |
| product | 705 |
| return | 3559411 |
| stock_transfer | 377512 |

Without the `fac.flat_inventory_id is null` condition, there should be around 6.4 million rows matching all conditions. With that specific conditions, at the current moment <100, but since the query execution has never been completed, I am not sure of the exact count.

The MySQL version is 8.0.28

Inverting the `and fi.storage_id not in (...)` criterion to `and exists (select 1 from storages s where s.zone <> 'virtual' and s.category <> 'virtual' and s.id = fi.storage_id)` did not improve performance.

The result of explain analyze on the first query is as follows:

```
-> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=3217330.41 rows=1) (actual time=15.897..15.897 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=3217330.41 rows=82301) (actual time=15.896..15.896 rows=1 loops=1)
        -> Filter: ((niyoweb.fi.unit_cost = 0.000000) and (niyoweb.fi.`status` not in ('lost','stolen','audit_lost','damaged','expired','invalid','audit_bad','deleted','audit_loss','cancelled','0','null')) and <in_optimizer>(niyoweb.fi.storage_id,niyoweb.fi.storage_id in (select #2) is false) and (niyoweb.fi.product_id is not null))  (cost=2958055.57 rows=202636) (actual time=15.826..15.826 rows=1 loops=1)
            -> Index lookup on fi using flat_inventories_source_type_source_id_index (source_type='audit_item_action'), with index condition: (niyoweb.fi.warehouse_id > 1)  (cost=2958055.57 rows=6405844) (actual time=0.376..2.500 rows=560 loops=1)
            -> Select #2 (subquery in condition; run only once)
                -> Filter: ((niyoweb.fi.storage_id = `<materialized_subquery>`.id))  (cost=3041.61..3041.61 rows=4497) (actual time=6.629..6.629 rows=0 loops=2)
                    -> Limit: 1 row(s)  (actual time=6.629..6.629 rows=0 loops=2)
                        -> Index lookup on <materialized_subquery> using <auto_distinct_key> (id=niyoweb.fi.storage_id)  (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=2)
                            -> Materialize with deduplication  (cost=3041.61..3041.61 rows=4497) (actual time=13.257..13.257 rows=11 loops=1)
                                -> Filter: ((niyoweb.s.`zone` = 'virtual') or (niyoweb.s.category = 'virtual'))  (cost=2591.90 rows=4497) (actual time=3.520..13.236 rows=11 loops=1)
                                    -> Table scan on s  (cost=2591.90 rows=23669) (actual time=0.030..8.437 rows=24704 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (niyoweb.fi.id between fcm.min_fi and fcm.max_fi)  (cost=0.91 rows=0) (actual time=0.068..0.068 rows=1 loops=1)
            -> Index lookup on fcm using fi_cogs_map_product_id_index (product_id=niyoweb.fi.product_id)  (cost=0.91 rows=4) (actual time=0.032..0.066 rows=7 loops=1)
```

The result of explain analyze on the second query is as follows:

```
-> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=3307894.65 rows=1) (actual time=615.728..615.728 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (fac.flat_inventory_id is null)  (cost=3307894.65 rows=82496) (actual time=615.727..615.727 rows=1 loops=1)
        -> Nested loop antijoin  (cost=3307894.65 rows=82496) (actual time=615.726..615.726 rows=1 loops=1)
            -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=3217148.99 rows=82496) (actual time=2.605..577.482 rows=14250 loops=1)
                -> Filter: ((niyoweb.fi.unit_cost = 0.000000) and (niyoweb.fi.`status` not in ('lost','stolen','audit_lost','damaged','expired','invalid','audit_bad','deleted','audit_loss','cancelled','0','null')) and (niyoweb.fi.product_id is not null))  (cost=2957260.45 rows=203115) (actual time=2.549..71.447 rows=14268 loops=1)
                    -> Index lookup on fi using flat_inventories_source_type_source_id_index (source_type='audit_item_action'), with index condition: (niyoweb.fi.warehouse_id > 1)  (cost=2957260.45 rows=6405844) (actual time=0.367..64.468 rows=15434 loops=1)
                -> Filter: (niyoweb.fi.id between fcm.min_fi and fcm.max_fi)  (cost=0.91 rows=0) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=14268)
                    -> Index lookup on fcm using fi_cogs_map_product_id_index (product_id=niyoweb.fi.product_id)  (cost=0.91 rows=4) (actual time=0.004..0.034 rows=11 loops=14268)
            -> Single-row covering index lookup on fac using PRIMARY (flat_inventory_id=niyoweb.fi.id)  (cost=1.00 rows=1) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=14250)
```

Changing `left join fi_assisted_costs fac on fac.flat_inventory_id = fi.id` to `and not exists (select 1 from fi_assisted_costs fac where fac.flat_inventory_id = fi.id)` does not run any better.

The current tmp table values `SELECT @@max_heap_table_size, @@tmp_table_size;` are 16777216 (16 MB) and 1000000000 (1 GB) respectively.

The source types are actually 'audit_item_action', 'grn_item', 'stock_transfer_item', return_item', and so forth. I had changed them in the original question to make them shorter. The `limit 1` is to find out the minimum id as `min(fi.id)` was taking more time to execute.

Comment: @user1191247 appended in the original post

Comment: Yes...my mistake...that is a typo (here, not in the actual query)

Comment: There were three keys on flat_inventory_id () and no primary key. Fixed it now. Updated DDL is added in the original post. However there is no improvement in query performance.

Comment: @user1191247 appended all answers in the question body

Comment: @user1191247 changing the query did not make it any faster. The current tmp table values are 16777216 (16 MB) and 1000000000 (1 GB) respectively.

The source types are actually 'audit_item_action', 'grn_item', 'stock_transfer_item' and so forth. I had changed them in the original question to make them shorter. I have appended the result of the Explain Analyze of the first query in the question. The limit 1 is to find out the minimum id as min(fi.id) was taking more time to execute.

Comment: If you're using `LEFT JOIN` and you want to filter out rows where those columns are NULL use `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: Don't change the tmp table settings to more than 1% of RAM -- else you run the risk of Swapping.

Answer (score 0):

- These indexes may help:

  ```
  fi:  INDEX(source_type, unit_cost)
  fcm:  INDEX(product_id,  min_fi, max_fi)  -- replacing (product_id)
  ```
- I think `LEFT JOIN ... IS NOT NULL` is identical to `JOIN` (without a null test).  Change to that; the Optimizer may be able to do a better job.
- This is useless, and it wastes time; remove it:

  ```
  left join  fi_assisted_costs fac  ON fac.flat_inventory_id = fi.id
    [where]  fcm.product_id is not null
  ```
- A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` does not make sense.  The query gives you some random result row; is that OK?
- This

  ```
    left join  fi_cogs_map fcm  ON fcm.product_id = fi.product_id
      and  fi.id between fcm.min_fi AND fcm.max_fi
  ```

  might be better phrased as

  ```
    [where]
        EXISTS( SELECT 1 
          FROM fi_cogs_map fcm
          WHERE fcm.product_id = fi.product_id
            and  fi.id between fcm.min_fi AND fcm.max_fi )
  ```
- This is very hard to optimize:

  ```
    fi.id between fcm.min_fi AND fcm.max_fi
  ```

  [*IP lookup*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges) may give better ideas.
- `PRIMARY KEY (id, warehouse_id)` is unusual.  What is the logic behind it?

After making those changes, I may come back an make another stab at helping you.

Comment: @user1191247 - thanks for pointing that out.  I misplaced that part when I shuffled the bullet items.

Comment: I think you meant `[where] fac.flat_inventory_id is null`, and it is quite selective, taking ~6.4M down to < 100.